# Understanding an example on pg.83 (Royden $4^{th}$ edition).

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, examples-counterexamples

The example is given below:

> [image]

My questions are:

1- I can see that $f_{1} = 1$ when $x \in (0,1),$  $f_{2} = 2$ when $x \in (0,1/2),$  $f_{3} = 3$ when $x \in (0,1/3),$  $f_{4} = 4$ when $x \in (0,1/4)....$

So I do not understand how $\{f_{n}\} \rightarrow f = 0$ on $E,$ could anyone explains this for me please?

2- why we are removing the zero from $E$ and $\chi$ domain and why are we removing $1/n$ from $\chi$?

Comment: If you included $x=0$ in the domain and used $f_n = n \chi_{[0, 1/n)}$, then the limit function would be $$f(x) = \begin{cases}1 & \text{ if }x = 0 \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise } \end{cases}$$ You would still have $\int_E f = 0$, so it would still be a valid example. Including or excluding $x = 1/n$ makes no difference.

Comment: So why when $x = 1/2$ our limit function is 0? could you clarify please?@Bungo

Comment: Because for every $n \geq 2$, we have $f_n(1/2) = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_0 \in (0,1]$

Then exists $m \in\ \Bbb{N}$ sicu that $\frac{1}{n}<x_0,\forall n \geq m$

Thus $x_0 \notin (0,\frac{1}{n}],\forall n \geq m\Longrightarrow f_n(x_0)=0,\forall n \geq m$

Thus $f_n(x_0) \to 0$

We remove the zero from the intervals because then we would have that $f_n(0)=1,\forall n \in \Bbb{N}$

But again it does not matter since the integrals over singletons are zero.

Comment: is your second line by Archemedian property ?

Comment: @Secretly yes it is..

Comment: can you please explain your idea of the proof by words?

Comment: @Secretly.. The explanation is that eventualy the point $x_0$  will not belong to the intervals..so $f$ will be eventualy zero..thus it will converge to zero since is eventualy constant zero.

Comment: for the line before last .... I can not understand how we will have $f_{n}(0) = 1$ for all $n$?

Comment: what are the singletons included in this case?

Comment: @Secretly  if the sets are of the form $1_{[0,\frac{1}{n})}$ then obviously they contain $0$ siince $0<\frac{1}{n},\forall n$

Comment: and what are the singletons included in this case?

Comment: @Secretly what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I am asking about the last line in your answer

Comment: @Secretly the lebesgue integral on every singleton is zero

Comment: my question is what singletons do we have ?

Comment: I realy do not understand your question and i do not understand where  do you have the problem to understand my answer..

Comment: "But again it does not matter since the integrals over singletons are zero" I am asking about this sentence in your answer, what singletons are you referring to ? is the measurable set upon we are integrating in this case is a singleton ? if so why?

Comment: If we add the singleton $1/n$ on the intervals $(0,1/n)$ we have that $\int 1_{(0,1/n]}=\int 1_{(0,1/n)}+\int 1_{\{1/n\}}=\int 1_{(0,1/n)}$

Comment: So it does not matter is we add $0$ or the points $1/n$ on the intervals

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience in answering my stupid questions :)

Comment: You are welcome..glad i could help. ;)

Comment: Could you please look at this question for me https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3405259/some-discussions-about-corollary-12-on-pg-83-in-royden-4th-edition